# Онлайн друзья

Tags: алгоритм, php

Хотелось бы узнать, как реализовать данную задачу? Есть список друзей обычный и помимо него, ещё онлайн друзья(а-ля ВКонтакте).

Вообщем, кто знает, напишите алгоритм, с помощью которого можно выводить список тех друзей, которые сейчас на сайте :)

Comment: зашел юзер на сайт, ставите ему в бд в поле `on_site` 1, вышел, ставите 0. Все кто 1, те и на сайте, конечно если это все у вас уже завязано на друзьях. Т.е. нужно выбрать только друзей.

Comment: Вот как это в друзья завязать?

Comment: Так у вас еще и не связано? Тогда вам сюда: http://hashcode.ru/questions/147885/php-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F

Comment: @Maris, мне не нужна самая функция Добавить в друзья. А именно - онлайн друзья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писали же уже миллион раз:)

У Вас проблема, наверное, в одном - Вы не логируете действия пользователей. Что печально. Т.е. Перешёл на страничку - добавили действие, отправил сообщение - добавили действие в базу. А чтобы понять  онлайн он или нет - время последнего действия < 3 минут? Значит онлайн, иначе пишем время его последнего действия как "последний раз был в сети". Чтобы понять кто из друзей онлайн - выбираем из "базы действия" те записи, где присутсвует друг пользователя которого смотрите, и  поступаем так, как я написал ранее:)